# How to use a separate router file in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, routes, mean-stack

This is my controller.

```
const catService = require('../service/catService');

var catController = {
    findAllCats: findAllCats
}

function findAllCats(req, res) {
    catService.findAllCats()
        .then((data) => { res.send(data); })
        .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
}

module.exports = catController;
```

Here is my routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var catController = require('../controller/catController');

router.get('/', catController.findAllCats);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the main app.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const { mongoose } = require('./config/db.js');
var { routes } = require('./routes/routes');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));

app.use('/cats', routes);
```

The problem is, the 'mongoose' variable is remaining unused (I have used mongoose in the Model and the DAO layer).

However, I am getting this error.
**TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined**

I understand I am missing something in the routing part. Can anyone help with this? I have to keep the router file as well.

Comment: Please complete your question for mongoose related issue, if any then also share /config/db.js file.

TypeError: Router.use()  -> solution below

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your main app.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    const { mongoose } = require('./config/db.js');
    // invalid import coz you are exporting router not object
    //var { routes } = require('./routes/routes');

    //require route like this
    var routes = require('./routes/routes');

    var app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.listen(3000, () => console.log('server started'));

    app.use('/cats', routes);
```

Comment: This worked. I confused between the two. Thanks a lot!